# Cloud Firestore with react-firestore-hook

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to figure out how to extract data from the cloud firestore database in my react app and I'm trying to use https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/tree/master/firestore#usedocument.

I am currently trying the following.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import updateAction from "../../projectForm/updateAction";
import { useDocument } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';


const Overview = props => {    
  const { state } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
  const FirestoreDocument = () => {
    const [value, loading, error] = useDocument(
      firebase.firestore().doc('hooks/umpIk64kmFK0eopsWP0T.title'),
      {
        snapshotListenOptions: { includeMetadataChanges: true },
      }
    ); 

  return (
    <div>

        <p>
        {error && <strong>Error: {JSON.stringify(error)}</strong>}
        {loading && <span>Document: Loading...</span>}
        {value && <span>Document: {JSON.stringify(value.data())}</span>}
      </p>

  </div>        
    );
};


export default Overview;
```

This produces an error that says:

> 'Parsing error: import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`useDocument` is a hooks.

According to the first rule of official [documents](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) - **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**

try to extract `useDocument` to the top level and use its function inside to call an action you want.

feel free to share more details.